# Generating a matrix with smaller values approaching the center

Tags: java, math, matrix

I'm looking to generate a matrix of integers where the integers are larger at the edges such as this:

```
[23] [23] [23] [23] [23] 
[15] [15] [15] [15] [15] 
[10] [10] [10] [10] [10] 
[10] [7] [7] [7] [10] 
[10] [4] [4] [4] [10] 
[10] [3] [3] [3] [10] 
[10] [3] [2] [3] [10] 
[10] [3] [1] [3] [10] 
[10] [3] [1] [3] [10] 
[10] [3] [1] [3] [10] 
[10] [3] [2] [3] [10] 
[10] [3] [3] [3] [10] 
[10] [4] [4] [4] [10] 
[10] [7] [7] [7] [10] 
[10] [10] [10] [10] [10] 
[15] [15] [15] [15] [15] 
[23] [23] [23] [23] [23] `
```

So  far so good! However, the problem i am having is keeping the max edge value along the top and bottom the same as the right and left edge, like this:

```
[23] [23] [23] [23] [23] 
[23] [15] [15] [15] [23] 
[23] [10] [10] [10] [23] 
[23] [7] [7] [7] [23] 
[23] [7] [4] [7] [23] 
[23] [7] [3] [7] [23] 
[23] [7] [2] [7] [23] 
[23] [7] [2] [7] [23] 
[23] [7] [2] [7] [23] 
[23] [7] [2] [7] [23] 
[23] [7] [2] [7] [23] 
[23] [7] [3] [7] [23] 
[23] [7] [4] [7] [23] 
[23] [7] [7] [7] [23] 
[23] [10] [10] [10] [23] 
[23] [15] [15] [15] [23] 
[23] [23] [23] [23] [23]
```

Notice the edges all equal the same maximum number 23. Getting them to all equal that same number is where i am having trouble (this is due to the different length and width). Here is how ive been generating my matrix:

```
public void generateChanceMatrix(){
    double ratio = numPointsX/numPointsY; //The difference in length of x and y

    for (int i = 0; i < numPointsX; i++){ //for each point
        for (int j = 0; j < numPointsY; j++){

            double max = Math.abs((numPointsX /2) - i); // these are responsible for generating larger numbers as you approach the edge
            double max2 = Math.abs((numPointsY /2) - j)* ratio; //this ratio is how i try to even out the difference in length of x and y

            if (max2 > max){ //see if the y axis is larger than the x, choose the larger
                max = max2;
            }

            chanceMatrix[i][j] = (int) Math.pow(2.2, max/2); //make it exponential instead of linear
        }
    }
}
```

How can i adjust this to make sure the values for all edges approach the same max value? For those curious, i am using this to generate a game world with blocked off map bounds, see below:

[image: Ships flying around the world!]

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'll be able to come up with a good example if you could explain what do the numerical values mean. as in how does 23 lead to 15 -> 10 -> 7 -> 4 -> 3 -> 2.

Comment: @GiladMitrani The numbers i generate start as 5-4-3-2-1-2-3-4-5, then when i set the Math.pow(2.2, max/2) i am creating an exponential growth, which increases the numbers exponentially as you approach the egde of the matrix. Ultimately these numbers are used as a chance of a wall appearing, where the chance is the chanceMatrix value at that point / the max chance matrix value. This means the edges must all equal the max for a 100% chance to spawn a wall. Does that make sense?

Comment: do you want the matrix to like like the first or the second ?

Comment: @whyn0t im looking for it to be like the second, where all edges reach the same maximum value

Comment: non square matrices are the problem, you are calculating the distance between center and the current (i,j) but this doesn't seem to work for non square matrices, because your method stars giving the right results once it reaches the square sub matrix

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use some interpolation based on the relative distance to the edge. I.e. the relative distance `t` will be zero in the middle of the matrix and 1 at the edges. And then you can do simple interpolation based on this value:

```
double relativeDiffX = 2 * abs(i - numPointsX / 2) / (numPointsX - 1);
double relativeDiffY = 2 * abs(j - numPointsY / 2) / (numPointsY - 1);
double t = max(relativeDiffX, relativeDiffY);
//now any interpolation
chanceMatrix[i][j] = (int) Math.pow(2.2, t); //this will produce values between 1 and 2.2
```

Comment: This is great! And works very well. Thank you so much for the help!

Comment: @Nico Schertler it's generating 2 for the edges and 1 for all the inside values, I thought that values should decrease toward the center ?

Comment: @whyn0t If you use integers, of course. If you use doubles or a different interpolant, then you will get the desired values. I just noticed that the original code contained this `(int)` cast, which I just copied. This is probably what confuses you.

Comment: well done, i wish he sends us the beta version of this game at least :p

Answer (score 1):

I'd solve the problem by parts:

1. Design an algorithm to fill a rectangle matrix (from 0,0 up to width,height) with *increasing* values.
2. The resulting matrix can be *duplicated symmetrically* (first, by horizontal symmetry, then by vertical symmetry) and it should result the final matrix.

Let's do it:

1. The filling algorithm:

   ```
   public int[][] generateChanceMatrix(Function function, int numPointsX, int numPointsY)
   {
           SymetricalMatrix symMatrix=new SymetricalMatrix(numPointsX, numPointsY);
           double r=((double)numPointsY) / numPointsX;
           for (int y=0; y < numPointsY; y++)
           {
                   for (int x=0; x < numPointsX; x++)
                   {
                           double value;
                           if (y <= r * x)
                           {
                                   value=function.getXValue(x);
                           }
                           else
                           {
                                   value=function.getYValue(y);
                           }
                           symMatrix.setCell(x, y, (int)value);
                   }
           }
           return symMatrix.getMatrix();
   }
   ```
2. The abstraction SymmetricMatrix that produce horizontal and vertical symmetric matrixes:

   ```
   private class SymetricalMatrix
   {
           private final int[][] matrix;

           private final double centerX;

           private final double centerY;

           private SymetricalMatrix(int width, int height)
           {
                   this.matrix=new int[height][width];
                   this.centerX=width / 2d;
                   this.centerY=height / 2d;
           }

           public void setCell(int x, int y, int value)
           {
                   double x1=x / 2d;
                   double y1=y / 2d;
                   this.matrix[(int)(this.centerY + y1)][(int)(this.centerX + x1)]=value;
                   this.matrix[(int)(this.centerY - y1)][(int)(this.centerX + x1)]=value;
                   this.matrix[(int)(this.centerY + y1)][(int)(this.centerX - x1)]=value;
                   this.matrix[(int)(this.centerY - y1)][(int)(this.centerX - x1)]=value;
           }

           public int[][] getMatrix()
           {
                   return this.matrix;
           }

   }
   ```
3. Finally, an abstraction to change the X and Y functions as you desire:

   ```
   private interface Function
   {
           public double getXValue(int x);

           public double getYValue(int y);
   }
   ```

And two proposed implementations:

```
    private class LinearFunction implements Function
    {
            private final double kx;

            private final double ky;

            public LinearFunction(int maxValue, int numPointsX, int numPointsY)
            {
                    this.kx=(double)maxValue / (numPointsX - 1);
                    this.ky=(double)maxValue / (numPointsY - 1);
            }

            @Override
            public double getXValue(int x)
            {
                    return this.kx * x;
            }

            @Override
            public double getYValue(int y)
            {
                    return this.ky * y;
            }
    }

    private class PowerFunction implements Function
    {
            private final double baseX;

            private final double baseY;

            public PowerFunction(int maxValue, int numPointsX, int numPointsY)
            {
                    this.baseX=Math.pow(maxValue, 1d / (numPointsX - 1));
                    this.baseY=Math.pow(maxValue, 1d / (numPointsY - 1));
            }

            @Override
            public double getXValue(int x)
            {
                    return Math.pow(this.baseX, x);
            }

            @Override
            public double getYValue(int y)
            {
                    return Math.pow(this.baseY, y);
            }
    }
```

Well, the final result is not 100% accurate, because even in a matrix with even number of rows (or columns), the values are not perfectly symmetrical. Something about rounding, I'm afraid. :-(

Comment: yep, the rounding messes things up, the function works fine with NxN matrices

Comment: Thanks for this! Ill check around and see if its better than the system i have in place now!